# Changing different attributes of textarea

Tags: javascript, text, attributes, formatting, textarea

I am trying to make a textarea in which I would be able to change the text inside to bold, italic, underlined etc...
So far, this is my code:

```
<body>
<form name="form1" action="" method="">
<div id="theForm">
<br><br>
<textarea id="theText" cols="40" rows="5" name="">
</textarea>
<br><br>


</div>
</form>
<button form="theForm" onclick="boldText()" type="button">Bold</button>
<button form="theForm" onclick="italicText()" type="button">Italic</button>
<button form="theForm" onclick="underlineText()" type="button">Underline</button>
</body>
</html>
<style>
#theForm
{ 
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:40%;
}
</style>

<script>
function boldtext() {
    theText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
</script>
```

I am not really sure how to even start the Javascript code..
Any help would be mighty appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theText in your code is undefined you need to get the element and assign it to the variable

```
window.onload = function() {
    theText = document.getElementById('theText');
};
```

this will create global theText variable. And your function need to be `boldText` (uppercase Text).

Comment: This pretty much helped with some addition of different code... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline css like

```
<textarea style="font-weight: bold">My Boldie</textarea>
```

Comment: If you use code indent it with 4 spaces or click `{}` icon.